# Mêlée cipher character build

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

While the general recommendation seems to build a cipher with ranged weapons (the [blunderbuss](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Blunderbuss) seems to be a favourite due it it hitting six times per shot thus greatly enhance [Soul Whip](http://pillarsofeternity.gamepedia.com/Soul_Whip)), I was wondering what was an optimal way to build a cipher that relies on mêlée weapons?

Comment: I haven't checked out the expansion or really, most patches since release (need to do that!) but, back at that time, the answer was 'don't.'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Do not

This seems to be the generic advise. [There is a good build for Ciphers](https://forums.obsidian.net/topic/78109-class-build-blunderbuss-cipher-hardpotd-difficulty/page-5#entry1890840) which strongly suggest that going mêlée is a path to pain and frustration. [There is an improved one on steam](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=871584933).